# Combining Shower Stall Components

Tags: shower, installation

I’m wondering if anyone has had any success or failure combining shower stall components from different manufacturers.

I’m looking at this [surround](https://www.homedepot.com/p/MAAX-Acrylic-32-in-32-in-x-72-in-2-Piece-Direct-to-Stud-Corner-Shower-Surround-Kit-in-White-105063-000-001-000/304726413) and this [enclosure/base](https://www.homedepot.com/p/OVE-Decors-Tampa-Pro-32-in-L-x-32-in-W-x-72-in-H-Corner-Shower-Kit-w-Pivot-Frameless-Shower-Door-in-SN-w-Shelves-and-Shower-Pan-828796075503/316115559).

I tried searching for a surround from the same manufacturer as the enclosure/base but they don’t offer anything that is direct to stud installation, which is what we need.

Thank you!

Comment: Where's the base? What do the installation instructions say on what is required?

Comment: "Build a Shower Kit with Radia Door 304726148 and Pan 204304030". https://www.homedepot.com/p/MAAX-Radia-32-in-x-32-in-x-71-1-2-in-Frameless-Neo-Round-Sliding-Shower-Door-with-Clear-Glass-in-Chrome-137443-900-084-000/304726148. https://www.homedepot.com/p/MAAX-32-in-x-32-in-Single-Threshold-Neo-Round-Shower-Base-in-White-101426-000-001-000/204304030.

Comment: Adding some kind of panels to the wall framing (and blocking at grab bar and door anchorage locations) is trivial and gives you a lot more options.

Comment: @LarryBud Apologies! It should be this link for shower enclosure/base. https://www.homedepot.com/p/OVE-Decors-Tampa-Pro-32-in-L-x-32-in-W-x-72-in-H-Corner-Shower-Kit-w-Pivot-Frameless-Shower-Door-in-SN-w-Shelves-and-Shower-Pan-828796075503/316115559

Comment: I'm sure that someone somewhere has had success combining shower stall components from different manufacturers, and I'm sure that even more people have had failure doing so. What is it that you're actually trying to ask us?

Comment: @FreeMan Just attempting to gage from people with learned experience with this if it’s a reasonable option or something not worth trying.

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], and read through the [help] on what kind of questions are on/off-topic here, you'll note that opinion based questions are _not_. They're reasonable to ask, we just don't deal well with them here.